new versions of fancyhdr break caesar_book class
When I compile caesar_example.tex, the page numbers do not appear.  They only show up if I use an older version of fancyhdr (e.g., this one).
I am using TeX Live 2022 on Debian.
Is this issue related to fancyhdr or caesar_book.cls?  What is the correct way to fix it, instead of downloading an older version of fancyhdr?

You could speed up getting a possible answer with some debugging: if you remove the non-fancyhdr stuff, do you still have no page numbers?  If you move the fancyhdr stuff into the preamble of a document instead of a cls file, does that help?  Can you get this into a single 30 line document that we can copy and paste?

It's not the fault of fancyhdr, but of caesar_book.cls which has
     74 \RequirePackage{fancyhdr}% helper package
     75 \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}% The running heads and feet do not have rules
     76 \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
     77 \fancyhf{}% set up the page numbering
     78 {\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}}
     79 \fancypagestyle{plain}{%
     80         \fancyhf{}
     81 }

(line numbers for reference). You can see on line 78 that the declaration for the footer is in braces, so its scope ends at the closing brace.
As far as I can see, the problem has always been there, but it eventually showed up when fancyhdr changed some internal.
Simple solution: add, at the end of the preamble,
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}

and inform the maintainer of the class about the issue.

Thank you!  For future reference, here is a link to the issue reported on the GitHub repository for this package: https://github.com/andythomas/TeX-sidenotes/issues/47

Thank you for reporting and making me aware. This is fixed now and I will upload to CTAN soon.
